# How do I create a func that return a match from values from two different arrays?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to create a game called set. Where if the user taps/clicks on three cards that match a certain criteria, then they win.

//when the user clicks on a button store that instance in button collection
     or current combination

//if current combination matches winningCombination

// the user has to click on correct buttons, if user clicks three buttons that dont match then user must try again

here is my code-

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    var logoImages: [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PicOne"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "picTwo"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PicTH\hree"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "picFour"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "picFive"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PicSix"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "picSeven"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "picEight")]
    var currentCombination: [UIImage] = []
    var winningCombinations: [UIImage] = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "PicOne"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "picTwo"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "picThree")]

    @IBOutlet var button: [UIButton]!


    @IBAction func HitBUtton(_ sender: UIButton) {


    }

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, Can I suggest you to put some code in your function? Normally is more better to ask how to solve a problem instead "write the code for me". Try by your self to understand how to create the function that check the combination.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using image only, I suggest you to create objects (for winning combination)  where you have a image property and a identification number property. In this case is more easy to check the combination: just matter to check if the identification number are correct or not. If you add more property you can add more criteria for the selection.